# Determining consistency by elimination- two zero rows

Tags: linear-algebra

1  -1   3   2 | b<sub>1</sub>

-2   1   5   1 | b<sub>2</sub>

-3   2   2  -1 | b<sub>3</sub>

 4  -3   1   3 | b<sub>4</sub>

By Gaussian elimination, I reduce the above matrix to:


1 -1 3 2 |b<sub>1</sub>

0 1 -11 -5 |-2b<sub>1</sub>-b<sub>2</sub>

0 0 0 0     |b<sub>1</sub>-b<sub>2</sub>+b<sub>3</sub>

0 0 0 0  |-2b<sub>1</sub>+b<sub>2</sub>+b<sub>4</sub>


The text book answer is:


b<sub>1</sub>= b<sub>3</sub> + b<sub>4</sub>

b<sub>2</sub>= 2b<sub>3</sub> +b<sub>4</sub>


I understand how the first consistency condition was reached (by combining the bottom to rows, setting them to zero and solving for b<sub>1</sub>).

 But how was the second condition reached? Why is it even necessary? Finally, why would there not just be two consistency conditions, such as:


0 =b<sub>1</sub>-b<sub>2</sub>+b<sub>3</sub>

and

0 =-2b<sub>1</sub>+b<sub>2</sub>+b<sub>4</sub>


which in my mind indicated that in order for this system to be consistent, the above two conditions must be met. I seem to be missing something key here and I think it comes down to not knowing how to determine consistency conditions when more than one zero row is present.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbook answer and your answer are the same system of two equations in four variables; the difference is simply the textbook answer simplified the system.

Comment: That was my first thought. However I don't know how the textbook simplified to the above solutions as in my solution, b<sub>4</sub> isn't present in both as it is in the textbook.

Comment: Well, it's a linear system of equations. How do you *normally* simplify and/or solve a linear system of equations?

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I see how the answer is reached when I treat the two zero rows as a system of linear equations and solve by subtraction for b1 and b2.